# Where is google analytics GA4 documentation for "page_view" event?

Tags: google-analytics-4

This [Event reference page](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/events) lists lots of interesting events but where is the documentation for the basic ones like "page_view", "event", "timing" and "exception" ?

Answer (score 1):

The page_view is in the document you provided

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/events#page_view

About the event :
In GA4 everything is an event.

Not like the UA distinct the hit type to `pageview, event, timing....`

So you can custom all the event if you need.

If you don't have idea, here is the recommend event document

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en

Comment: Ah with an underscore, not sure why I didn't find that, but thanks.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I just found that it depends which web browser I use.  Chrome is not showing me page_view, but Edge browser is: